# Node.js Async/Await issue

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am new to node, and I am having an issue with code I am writing.  I am fairly certain it is an async/await issue on my part.  I have a module secretManager.js that accesses a secret on GCP.

```
secretManager.js

 // Imports the Secret Manager library
 const {SecretManagerServiceClient} = require('@google-cloud/secret-manager');

 const projectId = 'projectId';
 const keyFilename = 'keyFile';

 // Instantiates a client
 const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient({projectId, keyFilename});

 const getSecretVersion = async (secret_id,version_id='latest') => {
    const version_name = `projects/${projectId}/secrets/${secret_id}/versions/${version_id}`
    // console.log(`version_name: ${version_name}`);
    try {
        // Access the secret.
        const [accessResponse] = await client.accessSecretVersion(request = {
            name: version_name
        });

        const responsePayload = accessResponse.payload.data.toString('utf8');
        console.info(`Payload: ${responsePayload}`);

        return responsePayload;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        return;
    }
};

module.exports = {
    getSecretVersion
}
```

It is being brought into my database.js file.  The secrets contain the db configuration settings, and I want to have them be passed into the "config" variable.  In database.js v1, the devConfig contains "undefined" values, and the connection is refused.  Shortly after the connection is refused, the payload from secrets is printed.  So basically, the call for config is returning after the database connection is attempted

```
databse.js v1

const util = require('util');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const secretManager = require('../lib/secretManager');

const config = secretManager.getSecretVersion('config');

let prodConfig = {   
  connectionLimit : 100, 
  user: config['user'],
  password: config['password'],
  socketPath: config['socketPath']
}

let devConfig = {
  connectionLimit : 10, 
  host: config['host'],
  user: config['user'],
  password: config['password'],
  charset: 'utf8mb4'
}


console.log(devConfig);
const pool = mysql.createPool(devConfig);


// Ping database to check for common exception errors.
pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
if (err) {
  if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
    console.error('Database connection was closed.')
  }
  if (err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR') {
    console.error('Database has too many connections.')
  }
  if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
    console.error('Database connection was refused.')
  }
}

if (connection) connection.release()

return
})

// Promisify for Node.js async/await.
pool.query = util.promisify(pool.query)

module.exports = pool;
```

database.js v2
Nothing seems to happen here...just see the database connection being refused.  However, I think I am closer to the solution with this one.  I think I may need to place the connection establishment, etc... within dbConfig.  That being said, I am not sure how that would work considering I am using util.promisfy to make the pool async.

```
databse.js v2

const util = require('util');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const secretManager = require('../lib/secretManager');

const dbConfig = async () => {
  console.log('in config');
  try {
      console.log(`Get config from secret manager`);
  const { getConfig } = await secretManager.getSecretVersion('config');
      console.log(getConfig);
      return getConfig;
  } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
      return;
  }
}; 


let prodConfig = {   
  connectionLimit : 100, 
  user: config['user'],
  password: config['passowrd'],
  socketPath: config['socketPath']
}

let devConfig = {
  connectionLimit : 10, 
  host: config['host'],
  user: config['user'],
  password: config['password'],
  charset: 'utf8mb4'
}

console.log(devConfig);
const pool = mysql.createPool(devConfig);


// Ping database to check for common exception errors.
pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
if (err) {
  if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
    console.error('Database connection was closed.')
  }
  if (err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR') {
    console.error('Database has too many connections.')
  }
  if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
    console.error('Database connection was refused.')
  }
}

if (connection) connection.release()

return
})

// Promisify for Node.js async/await.
pool.query = util.promisify(pool.query)

module.exports = pool;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, this code for an `await` `catch(e) { console.log(e);  return; }` is problematic.  This "eats" the promise rejection.  If you want to log it and still let the caller see the rejection (which is nearly always the case), you need to rethrow: `catch(e) { console.log(e);  throw e; }`.

Comment: thank you @jfriend00, I will make that change.